# How to measure and store specific distances of Price to a Moving Average

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, arraylist, trading

I'm a beginner with Python and coding.

Say I have a Moving Average and I want to set up conditions to store information between the duration where Price crosses above the MA then below.

The info I want to store is:

1. the Peak distance from Price to MA
2. the distance from the highest Price point to the Price point where Price crosses below MA.

[https://i.imgur.com/st9cc7D.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EovAb.png)

The data I use is a pandas dataframe with 4 columns, 2 cols are shift(1) of the other: data['Close' , 'Close Yesterday', 'MA', 'MA Yesterday']

Since I need to find the Peak distance and the Peak-to-Trough distance of each of the events-(Price crosses above and below MA), I have to clear the arrays each time an event has ended. That's where I'm struggling with.

Using for-loop then either nested if-statements or while then nested if's when the set condition is no longer valid to store the extrema values didn't seem to work because of **the arrays are already empty.**

Here's an example:

```
# Up Prices
price = []
# Up Price-MA diffs
diff= []
# Peak 
peak= []
# Peaks to Trough-(Price crosses below MA)
peak_trough = []

for i in range(len(data)):
        
    row = data.iloc[i:i+1,:]

    if row["Close Yesterday"].values[0] > row["MA Yesterday"].values[0]:  
    
        if row["Close"].values[0] > row["MA"].values[0]: 
            
            # store Up Prices
            price.append(row["Close Yesterday"].values[0])

            # take & store the Price-MA diffs 
            diff.append(row["Close Yesterday"].values[0] - row["MA Yesterday"].values[0])

    if row["Close Yesterday"].values[0] > row["MA Yesterday"].values[0]:

        if row["Close"].values[0] < row["MA"].values[0]:
    
            # store the Peak
            peak.append(np.max(diff))

            # store the Peak to Trough
            peak_trough.append(np.max(price) - row["Close"].values[0])
            
            # reset Prices
            price = []

            # reset Price-MA diffs
            diff= []
```

`price` and `diff` lists are aready empty when the 2nd nested `if`-statement is run.

How do you go about coding this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think as per above code we are working on two opposite condition use in 'if' and 'elif' inside a same iteration. If we say 'if' condition is cond-1 and 'elif' condition is cond-2. so for a row only one condition will be true either cond-1 or cond-2. so updating price and diff in a row in cond-1 and use in cond-2 is not looking correct.

so there are below approach to achieve above is -

1. need to run iteration twice independently first iteration is for cond-1 and inside it updation of price and diff list will happen with unique key identifier for example row index if row matters.

in second iteration run for cond-2 and use price and diff list updated in above iteration.

please note - no need to reset price and diff.

in a same iteration both condition is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
I made a typo not indenting the 1st nested if there.

Could you elaborate why reseting the lists is not needed?

Comment: If we go with the above suggested approach in my previous reply. In that case we can avoid list reset.

Comment: If we go as per above code snippet list reset will not work because for a row only one condition is met as i mention in above.     There are two possiblity in entire dataset for some rows cond-1 is met and for some rows cond-2 is met so if list is reset in each row than it wont work.  And also if we handle error in case of empty list found for cond-2 with mention approach. It will works as expectation.

Comment: Could you give an example for an unique key identifier for the lists?
Thanks!